# Power Automate how to change triger from Creating and Editing element to only editing element

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I prepered a Flow in Power Automate. And now i must change a trigger from Create and Edit element in Sharepoint List to only Create element in Sharepoint list. How could I do this ?

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to Power Automate Admin Center. Edit the flow.

2.Insert a new step -> Triggers -> When an item is created.
[image]
[image]
3.Delete the "When an item is created and modified".
[image]